# No such table in django

Tags: django, sqlite

When I click in my table in http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/, I see this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/home/table/
no such table: home_table.
```

I ran Python `manage.py makemigrations home`, `Python manage.py makemigrations` and `Python manage.py migrate` but they didn't work.

Comment: Try  `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Comment: Try `python manage.py showmigrations` to check which all migrations are applied to the DB. Can you also post those results?

Comment: @scharette, Thanks for your answers. It didn't work. I fixed it by deleting my sqlite db and running the migrations again.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge , Thanks for your answers. New migrations were not applied. I fixed it by deleting my sqlite db and running the migrations again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using  **sqlite** then:

Try unapply all the migrations using using command:

```
python manage.py appname zero
```

Then apply the migrations command again. If it still doesn't work then delete your sqlite db and run migrations again. It will work.

Comment: Many thanks. It was fixed with deleting the sqlite db. Nothing except this worked.

Comment: welcome @Fatemeh_A . Would you support this answer by accepting it. Just check the tick if you may. Much gratitude.

Comment: For the app that's giving you problems try `python manage.py migrate --fake appname zero`